# bitbake recipe for python package not working

Tags: python, yocto, pypi

I want to build using [bitbake recipe](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ndeflib/0.2.0%20package) for yocto.

I was using following recipe(python-ndeflib_0.2.0.bb) for this

```
DESCRIPTION = "NFC Data Exchange Format decoder and encoder."
SECTION = "devel/python"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "ndeflib"
inherit pypi setuptools

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "b7ae0c34f49289c44c292e24843cfeb1"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "baa86a48cf310cf77524f6fa04f5bd90775c4c290116b6b543aa3d6d65b721bf"
```

I was able to build it using this recipe but recently when I retried to build it using same recipe, I'm getting following error

> ERROR: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 8, output:
>   https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/n/ndeflib/ndeflib-0.2.0.tar.gz:
>   2017-09-23 12:18:56 ERROR 404: Not Found.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a very old release of meta-openembedded that is using an old base url for pypi downloads. If you can't use a more recent meta-openembedded I suggest not inheriting the pypi class and writing the recipe without it: The class doesn't do that much, setting  `SRC_URI` (to the correct url for downloading ndeflib) and possibly `S` manually in the recipe should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding this line

```
SRC_URI_prepend = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/0c/0f/b9d94cee7847697469c49a25b4d23236de534451990b83008e6bf4fab15b/ndeflib-0.2.0.tar.gz "
```

bitbake first tries to fetch from this URL